# Blocking and non-blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I came up with the following for a blocking and non-blocking queue implementation. Please suggest any changes/improvements/gotchas.

Blocking queue:

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {
    List<T> buffer;
    private static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 100;

    public BlockingQueue() {
        buffer = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void enqueue(T value) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(buffer) {
            while(buffer.size() >= MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
                buffer.wait();
            }
            buffer.add(value);
            buffer.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public T dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(buffer) {
            while(buffer.size() < 1) {
                buffer.wait();
            }
            T value = buffer.remove(0);
            buffer.notifyAll();
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

Non-blocking queue:

```
public class NonBlockingQueue<T> {
    List<T> buffer;
    private static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 100;
    private AtomicBoolean mutex = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public NonBlockingQueue() {
        buffer = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void enqueue(T value) throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            while(!mutex.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            if(buffer.size() < MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
                buffer.add(value);
                mutex.set(false);
                return;
            } else {
                mutex.set(false);
            }
        }

    }

    public T dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
        T value = null;
        while(true) {
            while(!mutex.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            if(buffer.size() > 0) {
                value = buffer.remove(0);
                mutex.set(false);
                return value;
            } else {
                mutex.set(false);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I think by non-blocking it means that the thread should not be blocked, so I used the `sleep` method. Please let me know if it has any issues.

Comment: `THread.sleep(100)` is a terrible idea, and it also blocks.  So "no."  C.f.: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/

Comment: @jtp04186. If I remove the Thread.sleep(100), that will make it non blocking right.

Comment: @user12331 either operation could block forever. They should try once and return failure if non blocking.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for critique ....

1. Why are you trying to use an AtomicBoolean as a mutex?  Use a primitive lock, or a `Lock` if you need more sophisticated behavior.
2. (Almost) any time you use `sleep` in an algorithm, you are doing it the wrong way.  In this case, the "wrong way" is a direct consequence of point 1. above.
3. If you want good performance in a situation where you have multiple producers and consumers, you should avoid doing a `notifyAll`.  For instance if there are N consumers waiting, and a producer adds a queue entry, then all N consumers will be woken up.  Ideally, only one consumer should be woken.

Comment: If I use Lock, won't it making it blocking?

Comment: Not if you call `tryLock`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you will be doing a lot of adding at the end and (in particular) removing from the beginning, I would use a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList`.

I'm also not sure what makes your `NonBlockingQueue` non-blocking.  It's sleeping, which is just as well.